# How to print something without this format : $[num]=[value] in GDB environment?

Tags: gdb

What I want is this :

```
(gdb) define mynext
Redefine command "mynext"? (y or n) y
Type commands for definition of "mynext".
End with a line saying just "end".
>print "------"
>print Location:
>where
>print "-------------"
>print Code:
>list
>print "---------------------"
>print Next:
>next
>end
```

This is what outputs is:

```
$1 = "-----"
....
```

I expect:

```
-----
....
```

I used call printf("opopo") also, but It print the return value of "opopo" which is 5. Just like this:$4 = 5

My question is: how can I print something without this format which is :$[num]=[value].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, `print` puts the printed value into the value history.  gdb provides two different ways to avoid this.

One is `printf`.  This works somewhat like the C function, but is a gdb command.  Use it like:

```
(gdb) printf "whatever you like\n"
whatever you like
(gdb)
```

Another is `output`.  This is a bit like the `print` command, but does not enter the value into the value history.

```
(gdb) output 5
5(gdb)
```

You can see from this that `output` also doesn't emit a trailing newline.  You would have to add that yourself.